# Automatic mergescript for github changing a versioning file

Tags: git

Assume a C/C++ program with the contents of a header file version.h as follows

```
#ifndef VERSION
#define VERSION
  #define MAJOR         0
  #define MINIOR        0
  #define BUILD_NUMBER  0
#endif
```

Attached to the build script contains this command

```
sed -i -r 's/(.*)#define(.*)BUILD_NUMBER(.*)(\w)/echo "\1#define\2BUILD_NUMBER\3$((\4+1))"/ge' include/version.h
```

which internally automatically increments `BUILD_NUMBER`.

Now assume on branch master version.h contains

```
  #define BUILD_NUMBER  20
```

And on branch A version.h contains

```
  #define BUILD_NUMBER  10
```

On merge is their a way on Github to add both these build numbers together
so that the master branch version.h contains

```
  #define BUILD_NUMBER  30
```